# How to get a beacons advertisement data in iOS background mode

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, core-bluetooth, beacon

I am trying to implement an app that simply detects a beacon and displays a notification while the app is in background mode.

I originally implemented CBCentralManager and received events in didDiscoverPeripheral which worked great but as soon as it goes into background mode it stops receiving events.

Since background mode is a requirement I implemented the CLLocationManager.  I marked location, background-central and background-peripheral as background modes in info.plist.  I also added NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription, NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription and NSLocationWhenInUsageDescription to info.plist.

The relevant code is like the following:

```
locMgr = new CLLocationManager();
locMgr.PauseLocationUpdatesAutomatically= false;
locMgr.RequestAlwaysAuthorization();
locMgr.AllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true;

var nsuuid = new NSUuid(uuid.ToString());
var nsidentifier = new NSString(identifier);

CLBeaconRegion region = new CLBeaconRegion(nsuuid, nsidentifier);
region.NotifyOnExit = truel
region.NotifyOnEntry = true;
region.NotifyEntryStateOnDisplay = true;

locMgr.StartMonitoring(region);


public void OnRegionEntered(object sender, CLRegionEventARgs e)
{
    is there anyway to get advertising info (instance id) of beacon in here?
    anything to identify the beacon besides the proximity id which is the same for multiple beacons?
}
```

I have a backend server that holds additional info about the beacon that i'd like to call to get name/message.  but this is keyed on the instance id of the beacon.

Does anyone know of a way to get the beacon info in background mode?  can i connect to peripheral or set up cblcentralmanager in the OnRegionEntered or any other way?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can setup silent push notification in ios. In which you have to create one web service which will take latitude and longitude from app after certain time duration and will return list of beacons available surrounded with particular region for that latitude and longitude.

Than after, You have to implement this method in your app delegate class:

func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)

This method will be called when your app will get any push notification from server. You have to update your app according to the list that you get.

Comment: This is an interesting approach.  Thanks.  but it requires the server to know the location of every beacon before hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply start beacon ranging at the same time you start beacon monitoring.  So in addition to this:

`locMgr.StartMonitoring(region)`

Do this:

`locMgr.StartRangingBeacons(in: region)`

If you do this, then for about 10 seconds after the first time you detect a beacon region (even in the background) you will get a callback to the following delegate method at a rate of once per second:

`didRange(beacons: beacons, region: region)`

The above parameter beacons will have an array of all the beacons matching that region as `CLBeacon` objects, and each one will contain the full identifiers:  proximityUUID, major, minor

Comment: So you can get the prox uuid, major and minor but no other info like the advertising data (instanceid) even after you detect the beacon. seems like a pretty big limitation in iOS. Thanks for the response and help

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "instanceid"?  It is true that iOS blocks you from accessing the bluetooth MAC, even with CoreBluetooth.  With CoreBluetooth though, it does give you  a device identifier that is a GUID mapped to the hidden bluetooth MAC.  But even this rotates periodically for the exact same device.